# My QUERY function in GOOGLE SHEETS is pulling the first row of the data set but it doesn't belong

Tags: google-sheets

I often use query functions to pull the top 5 (or bottom 5) values of a column. My basic formulas usually look like this:

=QUERY(A2:N32, "SELECT A,N ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 5")

but this time, it's grabbing the 1st row (N103SY, 34.7) as part of the query even though 34.7 does not come close to being within the top 5 values of all 31 possible values. The output IS correct starting with (N136SY, 62.0), so why the extra row at the top when it's not a part of the query?

```
N103SY  34.7
N136SY  62.0
N139SY  43.6
N127SY  43.3
N124SY  43.2
N119SY  41.0
```

Open doc (editable)...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oq1GvbsHdxpPM1wZ2HAXSjzYeA7dmT1Blq-raLilvbQ/edit#gid=735538815

Comment: [It is a guess from Google Docs, because you did not specify which headers to use](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en#:~:text=headers%20%2D%20%5B%20OPTIONAL%20%5D%20%2D%20The%20number%20of%20header%20rows%20at%20the%20top%20of%20data.%20If%20omitted%20or%20set%20to%20%2D1%2C%20the%20value%20is%20guessed%20based%20on%20the%20content%20of%20data.)

Comment: Ahh! Headers! Totally forgot that's an important element/argument! Thanks! (I guess I've just gotten lucky in the past), thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(A2:N32, "SELECT A,N ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 5", )
```

or upgrade to:

```
=SORTN({A2:A32, N2:N32}, 5, 2, 0)
```